# Statistic sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, statistics

I am drawing a chart to statistic, so i need to get data that chart have 12 months in x-axis and each month have 3 status part, each status part present its count value. I thought about sql like this:

```
SELECT status,count(*), created_date
FROM Profile
WHERE DATE_PART('MONTH', created_date ) = '6'
GROUP BY status
```

but this one just get a needed values of each in one month, if do that i must do it 12 time to get data 12 month. So i want get the data of 12 month in one query so have any one have solution for this?

And this my data table structure

```
  create table Profile (
        pro_id LONG not null primary key,
        created_date DATE null,
        status VARCHAR(75) null, // it just 3 status: applied, denied, processing
    );
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, make it easy to help you!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes the database is Postgres, based on the syntax of the query.

Well, your query is not taking year into account.  I suspect you really want something like this:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', created_date) as yyyymm, status, count(*)
FROM Profile
WHERE created_date >= date_trunc('month', now())
GROUP BY yyyymm, status;
```

However, you might want this as columns instead:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', created_date) as yyyymm,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE status = :status1) as status_1,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE status = :status2) as status_2,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE status = :status3) as status_3
FROM Profile
WHERE created_date >= date_trunc('month', now())
GROUP BY yyyymm;
```

This might be more suitable for graphing purposes.

Comment: actually i write it on postgres =)

Answer (score 0):

An MCVE would be more helpful as @jarlh suggested but reading between the lines, I figure that you are looking for something like this. You need to group by status and month to report for each of your 12 months.

```
SELECT status
      ,DATE_PART('MONTH', created_date )
      ,count(*) as month_count
  FROM Profile
-- WHERE DATE_PART('MONTH', created_date ) = '6'
GROUP BY status
        ,DATE_PART('MONTH', created_date )
```

Comment: output of that queries have some record with month duplicate so should i filter one more time by Map when i do with Java?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not possible to help further unless you post some example source data along with an example of what you want the output to look like.